# Show desktop icon in lancher in unity 2D

Tags: icons, unity-2d

I would like to have a "Show desktop" icon in my launcher. I've seen that there are already some threads about this issue but none of them solve the problem for Unity 2D (which I'm forced to use), alrady tried MyUnity or ccsm.

Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a little script and a .desktop file.

1. Instal wmctrl 
   `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`
2. Create a little script, open gedit and write this:
   [image]
3. Save the script eg:
   in your home as **"show_desktop.sh"**
4. Make the script executable
    **with** `chmod 764 /home/"user"/show_desktop.sh` **or** 
   `chmod +x /home/"user"/show_desktop.sh`
5. Now you can creat a desktop file to call the script. In the terminal type:
    `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/show-desktop.desktop`
6. Add the info.
    here you have an example:
   [image]
   (Feel fre to change any data in the file)
7. Go to the dash and serch for **"Show Desktop"**
   [image]
8. Drag and drop the icon into the Launcher

The credit for the script if for [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/10/show-desktop-applet-for-docky-gnome-do.html) , there is this "wmctrl" script for "docky", you can use it for unity launcher.

Cheers.

Comment: Works like a charm!
Thanks for the detailed explanation.